# Google Apps Script -GmailApp.search not returning all results (some are missing)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I am looking for some assistance as I did a bunch of searching and saw others with similiar problems but no solution.   Simply put the google apps script class/method GmailApp.search is not returning a full set of results, and it is clearly not due to a limit or anything I can see obviously like that.

Very basic usage...  I have a Gmail label, lets call it "labelname" with 118 messages in it.   When I search on www.gmail.com and enter "label:labelname" in the search box I get back 118 results as expected, but when I run: GmailApp.search('label:labelname'); from my script it returns only 116.

Script search syntax: 
threads = GmailApp.search('label:labelname');

After finding I am missing results I also added the count method to verify:
Logger.log(threads.length)

Which also returns 116.

I removed my label and re-added it to all 118 and GmailApp.search still only found 116.
I added my label to an additional message and tested again, now 119 on gmail.com and it went up to 117 in script result.  Still missing same 2 messages.

What could it be?   Their is nothing noticeable different about the 2 messages missing.  Same folder, same label, same exact style message send on the same date as others.

What could cause this?

Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions!

---

Comment: Are you searching for **messages** or **threads**? For example: in Gmail you have 8 threads. 7 where you only received 1 email and 1 thread where you replied and got a reply back. In that case you have 10 messages, but 8 threads. This really matters if you have "Conversation view off" in Gmail, because you will see individual messages, but `GmailApp` will only look for threads and never messages.

Answer (score 2):

GmailApp.search gives threads not individual mails.

If you unset the **Conversation View** in Gmail settings. It will show individual mails. So in that case there will be a mismatch between the count.

Comment: Appreciate this is an old thread, but this just caught me out and switching Gmail to Conversation View, gave me the search results as GmailApp. But is there a way to query messages over threads?