# Google Apps Script - GmailApp.search dates don't give same results as gmail search?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

So, I have this code

```
function readEmails()
{
 
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"Typed Reports/Security Reports" after:2022/3/25')
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var subject;
  var messages;
  var body;
  for(i = threads.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    Logger.log(i)
    subject = threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()
    messages = threads[i].getMessages()
    for(j = threads[i].getMessageCount()-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
      Logger.log(j)
      body = messages[j].getPlainBody()
      sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
      sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(subject)
      sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(body)
    }
  }
  
}
```

In gmail's settings, I have conversation view turned off. Running the query `label:"Typed Reports/Security Reports" after:2022/3/25` in gmail, it returns 47 messages.

Running the code, returns 80 lines filled with messages.

So I cross compared the two outputs.

The code gives everything that the gmail search does, plus all all the 23rd and 24th (minus two messages which came in on the 23rd at 7:05pm and 9:20am EDT respectively (11:05pm and 1:20pm UTC), so the equivalent of searching `label:"Typed Reports/Security Reports" after:2022/3/23` Minus two random messages.

Why does the code search after date not get respected correctly?

Every other question I've seen about inconsistencies with the code have been people's code giving *less* messages than the gmail search, not more and blatantly disregarding the search parameters. (basically the exact opposite issue as [Google Apps Script -GmailApp.search not returning all results (some are missing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520272/google-apps-script-gmailapp-search-not-returning-all-results-some-are-missing) which is the highest 'similar question' that comes up when I typed this all out)

Comment: Try Users.Message.list in Google Gmail API and utilize pageToken and q and you will probably get them all.

Comment: @Cooper I'm already getting them all. I'm getting more than what the search is supposed to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  If you have gmail configured to show messages not threads/conversations and do a search like `'after:2022/3/25'`, all emails that have arrived since 2022/3/25 will be shown in gmail. However, using the code I used, it pulls all threads that have a message that has arrived since 2022/3/25 and gives all of the messages in those threads.

So if you have a thread with 4 messages that came in on 3/3, 3/17, 3/26, and 3/27 respectively, the search in gmail shows the last two messages, while the script gets all 4.

Using the API does the right thing with message dates.

```
function readEmails()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var subject;
  var body;
  var messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', { q: 'label:"Typed Reports/Security Reports" after:2022/3/25', maxResults: '500', includeSpamTrash: 'true' }); 
  for (i = messages.messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
     body = messages[i].getPlainBody()
     subject = messages[i].getSubject()
     sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
     sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(subject)
     sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(body)
  }
}
```